# R - Duplicating rows based on a sequence of start and end dates

Tags: r

I have a data frame "DF" like this:

```
Flight.Start   Flight.End   Device      Partner   Creative   Days.in.Flight 
2015-08-31     2015-08-31   Standard    MSN       Video      35
```

What I need to do is "blow it up" like so:

```
Flight.Start   Flight.End   Date         Device      Partner   Creative   Days.in.Flight 
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-08-31   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-01   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-02   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-03   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-04   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-05   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-06   Standard    MSN       Video      35
2015-08-31     2015-10-04   2015-09-07   Standard    MSN       Video      35
```

ETC...... until Date variable hits 2015-10-04, then move on to next duplication

Essentially every row gets duplicated by the amount of **days in flight - 1** (since the row that already exists can account for a single day in the interval, and then a new column "Date" is filled out for the relevant dates for within that flight. So if a row has a start and end date of 9/1 and 9/5 respectively, 4 duplicate rows would be appended to the one already existing, a new column would be created (Date), and the date sequence of whatever the flight start and end dates are for the original row will fill out the column values.

All date values are formatted as date, days in flight is a num, and the rest are factors.

**EDIT**

In response to the duplicate question flagging:

To clarify, this is NOT like the case that has been flagged as a duplicate, because my question is not really focused on how to duplicate based on days in flight (I already know how to do that!), but rather how I can then add column to that output data frame and sequentially insert dates within the corresponding flight period. Thanks for the heads up...

Comment: hey @Jay, it is definitely not, thanks. I probably shouldn't have included all the stuff about duplicating the rows because I understand how to use `expandRows()`, but this question is more about how to fill out a sequential date column to go along with that expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with base R:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Flight.Start = as.Date(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-10")),
                   Flight.End = as.Date(c("2015-09-03", "2015-09-15")),
                   Device = "Standard",
                   Creative = "Video",
                   Days.in.Flight = c(3, 6),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

expanded <-mydf[rep(row.names(mydf), mydf$ Days.in.Flight), ]
data.frame(expanded,Date=expanded$Flight.Start+(sequence(mydf$Days.in.Flight)-1))

> data.frame(expanded,Date=expanded$Flight.Start+(sequence(mydf$Days.in.Flight)-1))
    Flight.Start Flight.End   Device Creative Days.in.Flight       Date
1     2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3 2015-09-01
1.1   2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3 2015-09-02
1.2   2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3 2015-09-03
2     2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-10
2.1   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-11
2.2   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-12
2.3   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-13
2.4   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-14
2.5   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-15
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way with `splitstackshape` and `dplyr`. Using `expandRows()` from the `splitstackshape` package, you can expand your data frame as you described. Then, you want to add a sequence of dates using `mutate()`. What I did was to group the data by the combination of `Flight.Start` and `Flight.End`, and use `seq()` to create a sequence of date for each group. `first()` is taking the first element of `Flight.Start` and `Flight.End`. In this way, you can create the sequence you want. I hope this will help you.

**DATA and CODE**

```
mydf <- data.frame(Flight.Start = as.Date(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-10")),
                   Flight.End = as.Date(c("2015-09-03", "2015-09-15")),
                   Device = "Standard",
                   Creative = "Video",
                   Days.in.Flight = c(3, 6),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#  Flight.Start Flight.End   Device Creative Days.in.Flight
#1   2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3
#2   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6

library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

expandRows(mydf, "Days.in.Flight", drop = FALSE) %>%
group_by(Flight.Start, Flight.End) %>%
mutate(Date = seq(first(Flight.Start),
                  first(Flight.End),
                  by = 1))

#  Flight.Start Flight.End   Device Creative Days.in.Flight       Date
#        (date)     (date)    (chr)    (chr)          (dbl)     (date)
#1   2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3 2015-09-01
#2   2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3 2015-09-02
#3   2015-09-01 2015-09-03 Standard    Video              3 2015-09-03
#4   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-10
#5   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-11
#6   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-12
#7   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-13
#8   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-14
#9   2015-09-10 2015-09-15 Standard    Video              6 2015-09-15
```

Answer (score 8):

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydf)`), replicate the sequence of rows by 'Days.in.Flight', based on that index, we subset the dataset (`.SD[rep(...`), grouped by 'Flight.Start', and 'Flight.End', we create the 'Date' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, .SD[rep(1:.N, Days.in.Flight)]][, 
     Date:= seq(Flight.Start , Flight.End, by = '1 day'),
     by = .(Flight.Start, Flight.End)][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `tidyverse` packages `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `purrr`.

```r
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mydf <- data.frame(Flight.Start = as.Date(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-10")),
                   Flight.End = as.Date(c("2015-09-03", "2015-09-15")),
                   Device = "Standard",
                   Creative = "Video",
                   Days.in.Flight = c(3, 6),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


mydf %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    Date = purrr::map(
      data, ~ seq(.x$Flight.Start, .x$Flight.End, by = "1 day")
    )) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(data, Date))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id Flight.Start Flight.End Device   Creative Days.in.Flight Date      
#>   <int> <date>       <date>     <chr>    <chr>             <dbl> <date>    
#> 1     1 2015-09-01   2015-09-03 Standard Video                 3 2015-09-01
#> 2     1 2015-09-01   2015-09-03 Standard Video                 3 2015-09-02
#> 3     1 2015-09-01   2015-09-03 Standard Video                 3 2015-09-03
#> 4     2 2015-09-10   2015-09-15 Standard Video                 6 2015-09-10
#> 5     2 2015-09-10   2015-09-15 Standard Video                 6 2015-09-11
#> 6     2 2015-09-10   2015-09-15 Standard Video                 6 2015-09-12
#> 7     2 2015-09-10   2015-09-15 Standard Video                 6 2015-09-13
#> 8     2 2015-09-10   2015-09-15 Standard Video                 6 2015-09-14
#> 9     2 2015-09-10   2015-09-15 Standard Video                 6 2015-09-15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>