# Generate timestamp for each ID in R in ascending order

Tags: r, time, timestamp, time-series

I tried to generate timestamp in R for my data and I'm having problem to create them in order where each ID will take group of timestamp for the period of 14 days and I need to create them in ascending order.

My data looks like :

```
ID      Lat          Long    Traffic   Time
1      -80.424      40.4242    54       1am
2      -80.114      40.4131    30       1am
3      -80.784      40.1142    12       1am
1      -80.424      40.4242    22       2am
2      -80.114      40.4131    31       2am
3      -80.784      40.1142    53       2am
```

And I want my data to be like this :

```
ID      Lat          Long    Traffic        Time_New
1      -80.424      40.4242    54       2018/01/01 01:00
2      -80.114      40.4131    30       2018/01/01 01:00
3      -80.784      40.1142    12       2018/01/01 01:00
1      -80.424      40.4242    22       2018/01/02 02:00
2      -80.114      40.4131    31       2018/01/02 02:00
3      -80.784      40.1142    53       2018/01/02 02:00
```

I used the code below to 24 hrs for each ID for the period time of 2 weeks
but I got this output but the order of the timestamp is not what I want plus it added the value of traffic from the previous values and I want to generate the new values of the new timestamp based on the average of the traffic flow of each ID.

```
library(data.table)
Data<- setDT(Data)[, .SD[rep(1:.N, ID)]][,Time_New:= seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 01:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-01-14 00:00"),by = "hour"),by = .(Lat, Long)][]




ID      Lat          Long    Traffic        Time_New           Time
1      -80.424      40.4242    54       2018/01/01 01:00        1am
2      -80.114      40.4131    30       2018/01/01 01:00        1am
3      -80.784      40.1142    12       2018/01/01 01:00        1am
1      -80.424      40.4242    54       2018/01/02 02:00        2am
2      -80.114      40.4131    54       2018/01/02 03:00        2am 
1      -80.424      40.4242    54       2018/01/01 02:00        2am
2      -80.114      40.4131    54       2018/01/01 03:00        2qm
3      -80.784      40.1142    30       2018/01/01 01:00        3am
3      -80.784      40.1142    30       2018/01/01 02:00        3am
3      -80.784      40.1142    30       2018/01/01 03:00        3am
```

As you see It listed  the first 3 IDs in the order I want then, it starts repeating ID 1, 2 and for ID 3 it put list of time from 1-3, and copy same traffic value.

Anyone has idea how to do generate the timestamp for each Id group in ascending order?

it will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are those dates being determined?

Comment: I need to generate sequence of timestamp in POSIXct format. I just need to make fake data and test my model on it

Comment: I understand that the time component of `Time_New` comes from `Time` column but it is not clear to me how the date changes after 3 observation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `lubridate` library:

```
library(lubridate)

Time = c("1am", "1am", "1am", "2am", "2am", "2am")

new.Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H%p", tz = "")
date(new.Time) = "2018-01-01"
> new.Time
[1] "2018-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2018-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2018-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2018-01-01 02:00:00 EST"
[5] "2018-01-01 02:00:00 EST" "2018-01-01 02:00:00 EST"
```

finally you can just add this column to your data frame

```
df$Time_New = new.Time
```

**Edit**: Comment made regarding adding dates over a multiple time period.

Suppose we wanted to have the first 3 entries on 2018-01-01 and the next 3 entries on 2018-01-02, we can do the following:

```
date(new.Time) = c(rep("2018-01-01",3),
                   rep("2018-01-02",3))
> new.Time
[1] "2018-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2018-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2018-01-01 01:00:00 EST"
[4] "2018-01-02 02:00:00 EST" "2018-01-02 02:00:00 EST" "2018-01-02 02:00:00 EST"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!That help to assign the time to each sensor!                                 Do you know how can I generate more than 24 hrs? like for 2 weeks?

Comment: @Reta : Edit made to post. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use base R's `as.POSIXct`

```
refdate <- "2018-01-01"
dt[
    , Time_new := as.POSIXct(paste(refdate, Time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %I%p")][
    , Time := NULL][]
#   ID     Lat    Long Traffic            Time_new
#1:  1 -80.424 40.4242      54 2018-01-01 01:00:00
#2:  2 -80.114 40.4131      30 2018-01-01 01:00:00
#3:  3 -80.784 40.1142      12 2018-01-01 01:00:00
#4:  1 -80.424 40.4242      22 2018-01-01 02:00:00
#5:  2 -80.114 40.4131      31 2018-01-01 02:00:00
#6:  3 -80.784 40.1142      53 2018-01-01 02:00:00
```

Here I assume that the date is always the same (your sample output shows a change in date which is neither clear nor explained).

---

### Sample data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("ID      Lat          Long    Traffic   Time
1      -80.424      40.4242    54       1am
2      -80.114      40.4131    30       1am
3      -80.784      40.1142    12       1am
1      -80.424      40.4242    22       2am
2      -80.114      40.4131    31       2am
3      -80.784      40.1142    53       2am")
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to generate more dates?

Comment: @Reta Unfortunately your post is fairly vague on how you generate dates; so the answer would be "yes of course you can generate more dates", the details of which depend on your *specific* problem statement (which is absent).

Comment: I've followed the command in the last comment  here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181287/r-duplicating-rows-based-on-a-sequence-of-start-and-end-dates  But I changed it to hour instead of day.